# (Proof verification) Kaye Exercise 3.5.5, partial trace in larger system

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, density-matrix, linear-algebra

This is the exercise as stated in Kaye's book, Introduction An Introduction to Quantum Computing:

> Show that for any density operator $\rho$ on a system $A$, there exists a pure state $|\psi\rangle$ on some larger system $A \otimes B$ such that $\rho = \text{Tr}_B|\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$ and $\dim(A)\geq \dim(B).$

Here's my solution: Suppose $\rho = \sum_{k=1}^m p_k |k\rangle \langle k|$. Wlog, we can assume that $\{|k\rangle\}$ are linearly independent. Let $B=\text{span}_{k=1,...m}\{|k\rangle\}$ and select $\{|\varphi_i\rangle\}_{i=1}^m$ an o.n.b for $B$. Then $\dim(A)\geq \dim(B)$ and for the state $|\psi\rangle = \sum_k \sqrt{p_k}\,|k\rangle_A|\varphi_k\rangle_B$ we get $\rho = \text{Tr}_B |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$.

Is this solution correct? I am specifically concerned about the part where I assumed that $\{|k\rangle\}$ are linearly independent. My reasoning is that even if $\rho$ can be written in a way that contains linearly dependent states we can always change our $p_k$ accordingly and get rid of them one by one leaving us with the same $\rho$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfectly reasonable answer. The only thing that I'd change is that I would make $\{|k\rangle\}$ the eigenbasis of $\rho$. Then, by definition, $\{|k\rangle\}$ gives you an orthonormal basis. This automatically takes care of the "we can always change our $p_k$" aspect.